# Search multiple models at once with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, ransack

I have a search form in the header of my app and I would like to use this search form to search through multiple models within the application.

For example a request like `/search?q=rails` should trigger a search through multiple models like `Work`, `Project`, `User` and their defined attributes. I wanted to use Ransack because I already use it on the `Work` model in a different area of the app.

I think I don't quite understand Ransack yet and the documentation always points out that you have to define `@q = MyModel.search(params[:q])` to use it in the form `search_form_for @q`. Is there a way where you don't have to define a specific model in advance? And just pass in the parameter name like `search_form_for :q`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Okay, after asking the question the answer popped into my head.

Instead of the `search_form_for` helper I'm now just using the `form_tag` helper in the following way:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
<%= end %>
```

and in the search action I just do:

```
q = params[:q]
@works    = Work.search(name_cont: q).result
@projects = Project.search(name_cont: q).result
@users    = User.search(name_cont: q).result
```

This works for me. I hope this also helps someone else.

Comment: Here in 2021 to say still a brilliant and simple solution

Comment: It's still great in 2023, but it bears mentioning that apparently the syntax has changed a little. "ransack" instead of "search" worked for me.