# Ruby on Rails ransack gem search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

i want to implement a search that goes through multiple models.

Found this [stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775207/search-multiple-models-at-once-with-ransack) that uses ransack and tried it right away. But I can't seem to get it to work.

in my controller :

```
def search
  @quotes = Quote.search(title_cont: q).result
  @books = Book.search(title_cont: q).result
  @users = User.search(username_cont: q).result
end
```

routes

```
get '/search', to: 'application#search'
```

view

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= f.label :title_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :title_cont %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is the problem you have now? Do you get any error?

Comment: Never mind, I've figured out your problem. Writing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `params[:q]` instead of `q`. This should work

```
def search
  @quotes = Quote.search(title_cont: params[:q]).result
  @books = Book.search(title_cont: params[:q]).result
  @users = User.search(username_cont: params[:q]).result
end
```

Also, f.label and `f.search_field` doesn't work with `form_tag`. You should use `label_tag` and `search_field_tag` instead

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= label_tag :title_cont %>
  <%= search_field_tag :title_cont %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried that but I dont see any results. Do I have to set up @results for that? And how would I show them on a result page?

Comment: @flenning12 I cant tell because I never worked with ransack, but I can give some pointers. Check this for a demo https://www.sitepoint.com/advanced-search-ransack/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two fields in your search form, you should only have one search field.

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= label_tag :title_cont %>
  <%= search_field_tag :q %>
<% end %>
```